# Android: Options Menu error?

Tags: android, xml, android-menu

When I click button menu I found error but If I click menu on below error show

> actionbar not found error. android.view.InflateException: Binary XML
>   file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class
>   android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView

Logcat :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.getMenuView(ListMenuPresenter.java:101)
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.getListMenuView(ToolbarActionBar.java:522)
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.access$400(ToolbarActionBar.java:47)
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelView(ToolbarActionBar.java:581)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1279)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyDownPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1419)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyDown(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:905)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:241)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3981)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2253)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1874)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1865)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2230)
    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.getMenuView(ListMenuPresenter.java:101) 
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.getListMenuView(ToolbarActionBar.java:522) 
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.access$400(ToolbarActionBar.java:47) 
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelView(ToolbarActionBar.java:581) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1279) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyDownPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1419) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyDown(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:905) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:241) 
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3820) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3981) 
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2253) 
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1874) 
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1865) 
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2230) 
    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141) 
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) 
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.se_ed.current.CurrentActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_clear_all_recents"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Clear Recents"/>
```

Comment: Is it your full main_menu.xml?

Comment: @Alexey : can you please let me the solution of this issue,as I am facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your `main_menu.xml` in your project looks the same as your put here, you should add closing tag `</menu>` to look like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.se_ed.current.CurrentActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_clear_all_recents"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Clear Recents"/>

.... more items
....
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

full main_menu.xml

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.IPJ1988.hytexts.ebookstore.activity.HomeActivity">
<item android:icon="@drawable/android_search"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_syn_new"
    android:title="@string/action_syn_new"
    android:onClick="syn_new_ebook"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_syn"
    android:title="@string/action_syn"
    android:onClick="syn_ebook"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_picker"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:title="@string/picker_sesrch"
    android:onClick="picker"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_list"
    android:orderInCategory="5"
    android:title="@string/action_list"
    android:onClick="listGrid_View"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="6"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:onClick="setting"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:orderInCategory="7"
    android:id="@+id/action_download_all"
    android:title="@string/download"
    android:onClick="downloadAll"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Comment: edit your post and insert the code into. After editing delete this answer as it is not answer.